# how to make a tkinter widget global

Tags: tkinter, global, python-3.9

I am making a python program that has multiple Tkinter GUI's, and one of the GUI is defined inside a function and i want to access a Tkinter(defined inside the function) element outside of the function and how can I do that?

python version: 3.9(Conda)

code example:

```py
from tkinter import *

firstGUI = TK()
testBox = Text(firstGUI)
bt = Button(firstGUI,text="Launch the second gui",command=test)
firstGUI.mainloop()

def putText():
   sample = testBox.get()
   testBox2.insert('1.0',sample) #how i can access the testbox2 here    

def test():
   secondGUI = Toplevel()
   testBox2 = Text(firstGUI)
   button = (secondGUI,text="SEND",command=putText)
   secondGUI.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add something like `global widget_name` inside the function.

Comment: @acw1668 i tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: Please provide minimal code example!

Comment: You can simply pass `testBox2` to `putText()`: `def putText(testBox2)` and `button = Button(secondGUI, text="SEND", command=lambda: putText(testBox2))`. Or just add `global testBox2` inside `test()`.

Answer (score 0):

So I know you might be new to this, but there are a lot of issues with your code.

- First: Always define the functions in the beginning of your script.
- Second: Try to avoid * imports, put use import tkinter as tk
- Third: You create widgets (Text, Button), but you don't place them into your
  widgets. I did this using `grid`.

Here is an example of what I think you want to achieve. If you consider these things, you don't need to make anything global.
I would suggest you to watch more basic tkinter/python tutorials.
Good luck!

```
import tkinter as tk


def putText():
    txt = "Hello World\n"
    testBox.insert('end', txt)  # how i can access the testbox2 here


def test():
    secondGUI = tk.Toplevel()
    button = tk.Button(secondGUI, text='SEND', command=putText)
    button.grid(row=0, column=0)
    secondGUI.mainloop()


firstGUI = tk.Tk()
testBox = tk.Text(firstGUI)
testBox.grid(row=1, column=1)
bt = tk.Button(firstGUI, text="Launch the second gui", command=test)
bt.grid(row=0, column=0)

firstGUI.mainloop()
```